# Dynamic list instead of In Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

This is my main query of my stored procedure (Sales):

```
select * 
from Customers 
where Customers Codes in ('11232133', '654664666',
                          '243423424', '123123231',
                          '967868686', '122343245', '636463636')
```

I want my stored procedure (Sales) connect it with Excel and refresh dynamically (VBA). Instead of customers codes that are contained in the `IN` clause, I want to show the customer name in the table in Excel and refresh dynamically to stored procedure.

What is the right process?

This is my table in Excel that I want to insert to my stored procedure dynamically:

| Customers Codes |
| --- |
| 324516432 |
| 794536703 |
| 523682134 |
| 943321789 |
| 023456763 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](//xyproble.info). If you want the list of codes to be able to be amended and referenced by your procedure, the data should be stored in SQL server, and you should be using a `JOIN`/`EXISTS`.

Comment: Why in the world do you want to open a connection to excel and just assume it is correct? This screams of a design idea gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Syntax error. Extra `,` before closing `)`.

Comment: You missed the lack of a part separator on `Customers[.]Codes`, @jarlh  ;)

Comment: Pass a table variable with the codes to the procedure and use it in the query.

Comment: @Larnu. I'm sorry, it's been a long day, with numerous hardware, software and networking problems...

Comment: Don't worry, we all have those days, @jarlh . I don't miss the day a PSU exploded and took out 2 switches in the server room last year. >_<

Comment: @stickybit can you  please write an example?